Importing an cfg file( existing enviroment configuration) in visual studio code
I have a CFG file(environment) with some existing libraries that I would like to import into Visual Studio code. I have tried everything I knew but can't find any solution.
Is this possible?
Can you please guide me? Thanks a lot! :)
